# NFC Android Wifi Pairing

Tags: java, android, nfc

Hi im new here and I hope somebody can help me:

In the following Specification on Page 22 (Table 4: Binary Content of a Minimum Wi-Fi Handover Select Message)
is a sample Tag. I want to write this byte-Array on a NFC-Tag (first with the same SSID and so on) to see what happens.

http://www.maintag.fr/fichiers/pdf-fr/nfcforum-ts-connectionhandover-1-1.pdf

But during the write action, a Format failure occurs. Here is my Array I want to write (Except of the Mac everything should be the same - in the Spec stands that the Mac is set to Zero if it is not known).

```
byte[] mydata = new byte[] {
    /* Record 1 */
    (byte) 0x91,
    0x02,
    0x0a, //0x01 or 0x0A?
    0x48, 0x73, // Hs
    0x10,

    /* Record 2 */
    (byte) 0xd1,
    0x02,
    0x04,
    0x61, 0x63,
    0x01,
    0x01,
    0x30,
    0x00,

    /* Record 3 */
    0x5a,
    0x17, // 23 bytes type application/vnd.wfa.wsc 
    0x42, // 66 bytes payload // TODO
    0x01,
    0x61, 0x70, 0x70, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x63, 0x61, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6f, 0x6e, 
    0x2f, 0x76, 0x6e, 0x64, 0x2e, 0x77, 0x66, 0x61, 0x2e, 0x77, 0x73, 
    0x63,  //application/vnd.wfa.wsc 
    0x30, // ID // FROM HERE included 66 bytes
    (byte) 0x104A, 
    0x0001,
    0x10,
    (byte) 0x100E,
    0x0039, //TODO FROM HERE down 57 byte
    (byte) 0x1026,
    0x0001,
    0x01,
    (byte) 0x1045,
    0x0008, // SSID LENGTH
    0x48, 0x6f, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x57, 0x4c, 0x41, 0x4e, // HomeWLAN
    (byte) 0x1003,
    0x0002,
    0x0020, // WPA2PSK
    (byte) 0x100F,
    0x0002,
    0x0008,
    (byte) 0x1027,
    0x000E,
    0x4d, 0x79, 0x50, 0x72, 0x65, 0x53, 0x68, 0x61, 0x72, 0x65, 0x64, 0x4b, 0x65, 0x79, // KEY
    (byte) 0x1020,
    0x06,
    (byte) 0x000000000000
};
```

I also downt know if the first payload length is 0x01 oder 0x0a because in my opinion the length is only 1 - I downt know where 10 byte should be stored in the first record?

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Record 2 is actually embedded inside record 1. Record 2 is 9 bytes total, which, together with the version number of record 1 (1 byte), makes 10 bytes.

Comment: BTW: There is an updated version of the Connection Handover specification available at http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/spec_list/#refapps

Comment: Ah thx ok now I know where the 10 bytes come from. thx for the update link. The problem i have to solve is WIFI pairing but im completely new so I have some understanding problems.
1) it is a static handover this means I just need the selector tag is that right? or do i also need the requestor tag on the phone? because what happens if I have stored the selection-Tag on the NFC-Tag and i read the Tag with my phone? I think in this case i just need to read and parse the data and then config the WIFI Manager or is there a response necessary?

Comment: Problem solved, 0x00, 0x06 @ mac length instead of 0x06. now the length is ok.

Comment: In case of reading a tag with Handover data, no response is possible, so it is not necessary.

Comment: Thx for your replies. I have 1 more question - I want to find the constants for the wifi data record (AES,WPA2PSK, ...) I found the following : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa814090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx but this is not the real spec. The problem is I want to config different wlan configs and I need to know how this record is build and which constants are needed in which order. For example for open wlan I will not need the key so the size will be 0. Maybe someone knows a keyword where I can find the information? Big Thx!

Comment: The spec is maintained by the [Wi-Fi Alliance](http://www.wi-fi.org/).

Comment: Consider using an [NDEF editor](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be looked up in the current Wi-Fi Simple Configuration specification, which is the underlying specification for Wi-Fi Protected Setup.  The current version is 2.0.2, and it can be acquired from the Wi-Fi Alliance ( http://www.wi-fi.org ).

In the WSC 2.0.2 spec, head to section 10.2 for the structure, and section 12, which defines the types and lengths for the TLV blocks in that structure.